# B-trees using C

Tags: c

can any one provide me a link for B-tree code in C,have understood the algorithm but still have problems in coding it

Comment: This is not the right site for just asking for a code dump.  We'll be glad to help with specific questions as you work on it.

Comment: Found via Google: http://www.mycplus.com/free-utilities/b-tree-implementation/

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen why?  Perfectly normal to ask for a library recommendation.  Why would anybody roll their own B-tree?

Comment: @MK, the "still have problems in coding it" sounds like he's supposed to write one, perhaps for homework.  It doesn't read like a request for a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c++
http://touc.org/btree.html

c (slightly fancier than normal)
http://code.google.com/p/high-concurrency-btree/downloads/list